# Multi-threaded application is hanging on Thread.Join()

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging

I can reproduce a situation where my multi-threaded console application hangs at `Thread.Join()`.

How can I, in real-time, debug and figure out which thread is hanging? Is there a method that I can use?

Comment: It's whatever thread you're joining on.  What other thread could it possibly be?

Comment: Each thread that I'm joining is printing a statement just before it terminates but for some reason, the thread doesn't terminate. Im thinking maybe the thread is not release resources properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a bunch of threads and you calling Join on each in a loop and not sure which one hangs you, couple of things you can do:

1. Threads can be named.  name your threads when creating, then just before calling Join write the name of the thread you're about to join on (to debug message or console window).  This will tell you which thread by name.
2. You can try to attach debugger to process, break execution, then see which threads and where they are.
3. general trace messages in thread functions.

Comment: You could also grab a memory dump and do `~* e !clrstack` in windbg with SOS extensions loaded and see if any of the stacks suggest either a infinite loop or if any of the threads waiting for synch mechanism

Comment: Thanks! I found the hanging thread. It was hanging at a webservice call.